# How do you link QGIS legends in different print composers?

Tags: print-composer, legend, qgis-print-layouts, duplication, link

I have a long linear QGIS project with about 20 separate print composer layouts.  I'd like to link each legend to the original one, so I don't have to copy and paste 20 times every time I need to update the legend.

What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: I don't think you can link legends, but that would be a nice new feature if you want to submit a [feature request](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues) for it. But, have you tried using one Atlas instead of 20 separate layouts?